# php strtotime 'now' and '-1 month' showing same date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

My two variables

```
date("Y-m", strtotime ( '-1 month'))
```

and

```
date("Y-m", strtotime ( 'now'))
```

are both showing 2020-03 currently on todays date 30/03/2020
Currently it's march 2020-03 so -1 month should show 2020-02

What are my solutions to getting around this?

Thanks

Comment: Honest question: what day would you say is one month before today? The problem is happening because PHP considers it to be February 30th, and since that doesn't exist, it gets rolled over into March.

Comment: To follow up on @iainn comment, if you `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime ( '-1 month'))` you'll see it's `2020-03-01`

Comment: I would never depend on `strtotime` automagic for such calculations, especially if it involves vague definitions such as "one month".

Comment: I get the issue... so am I best doing something like $lastmonth=date("m", strtotime ( 'now')); then doing if ($lastmonth>1) {$lastmonth=$lastmonth-1} else {$lastmonth=12};

Comment: This is specific to running this function on March 30th, as 1 month ago was Feb 30th which does not really exists :)

Comment: 'first day of last month' as per @Nick does the trick

Answer (score 2):

One way to work around this is to use the `first day of last month`:

```
echo date("Y-m", strtotime('first day of last month'));
```

Output (as of 2020-03-30):

```
2020-02
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/eq6UA)

Comment: perfect !!! Thank you. Any fall backs or issues with any other scenarios to this?

Comment: @HenryAspden it shouldn't have any issues. You can test it with code such as `echo date("Y-m", strtotime('first day of last month', strtotime('2020-01-15')));` which will give you the `first day of last month` relative to `2020-01-15` which is `2019-12`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
if (date("Y-m") == date("Y-m", strtotime ("-1 month"))) {
    echo date("Y-m", strtotime ("last day of last month"));
} else {
    echo date("Y-m", strtotime ("-1 month"));
}
```

[**demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/G9MpkJ)

Comment: No real need for the `if`, just using `date("Y-m", strtotime ("last day of last month"))` will work.

Comment: In this case yes! But this also working on days like on MySQL.